# Is there way to use push notifications in our ionic 4 project?

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ionic4, android-push-notification

We currently have an Ionic and Firebase project that we coded. In this project, we want to use push notifications. But our trouble is: 
We are looking for a push notification plugin, like WhatsApp application. For example, when we send a message to a person, we want the notification to go to the person we're texting from, not everyone. But we couldn't find a free way to do that. Do you have any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**Firebase Cloud Messaging**  By using cordova-plugin and ionic-native:[Ref. Url](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm)

```
  import { FCM } from '@ionic-native/fcm/ngx';

constructor(private fcm: FCM) {}

this.fcm.getToken().then(token => {

  //you can store device token in firebase, later you can target push notification from firebase console this token id
  backend.registerToken(token);
});

this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
  if(data.wasTapped){  / * true , means the user tapped the notification from the notification tray and that’s how he opened the app. */
    console.log("Received in background");
  } else {// false , means that the app was in the foreground (meaning the user was inside the app at that moment)
    console.log("Received in foreground");
  };
});

this.fcm.onTokenRefresh().subscribe(token => {

  //update device token
  backend.registerToken(token);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend you to use FCM plugin. It has no methods to manage your notifications in your app (clear all or clear some special notification.

It is  better to use [phonegap-push-plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push) or One Signal